# Oracle Synonyms in Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I am exploring Entity framework 6 in VS.net 2013. After installing the oracle drivers and creating the edmx file and using Entity Wizard. 
For some reason I am not able to view all the Oracle Synonyms. 
I am able to view only few Under Views.

Is there any way we can we all the Synonyms?

Comment: They [aren't supported](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/124) but there seem to be [work-arounds](http://forums.asp.net/t/1771938.aspx?A+problem+to+view+synonym+of+Oracle+in+the+Entity+Data+Model+Designer).